# How to split tone in Nik Silver Efex Pro 2?

Tags: post-processing, nik-software, split-tone

I have Lightroom 4 and Nik Software

I am wishing to create various toning within a photo.

What I  mean by this  is if I have a photo with a chair with cushions , lamp shade, rug etc I would like to make the cushions a separate brownish tone and the lamp a more mustard tone, rug a more beige tone and leave others parts of the photo in black and white.

Is there anyway to do this within Nik Silver Efex Pro 2

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you have come to realise, Nik Silver Efex Pro does not support control points for tonal changes. This leaves you a couple of choices:

**Upgrade**

If you have Photoshop, then upgrade to Photoshop version so that you can use layers.

Your workflow would then be:

- Export to Photoshop
- Run Silver Efex for first layer to tone for specific parts of image
- Select background layer and repeat
- Now use layer masks or eraser tool to blend the resulting images together

**Long Workflow**

You can achieve the same results as above by using separate images

Your workflow would then be:

- Export to Silver Efex and tone for specific parts of image
- Repeat above steps as required
- Now use an image manipulation tool that supports layers. This could be anything from The Gimp, Photoshop Express to Paint.NET
- And apply the masking/erasing to achieve your composite image

**Not Quite Shorter Workflow**

You can use the above workflow and then use perfect layers to highlight the generated images with silver effects and then use [OnOne Perfect Layers](http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/perfect-layers/) to create the composite.

This allows you to stay within Lightroom to achieve your effex [pun intended]